# (in Vue) How to update props has reference types in child component without affecting main component?

Tags: vue.js, reference-type, vue-props

I am trying to create sub components under a main component and sending props from main to sub components. I would like to have possibility if user makes changes on sub component it will not affect main component. I mean one way binding.

to see full repository https://github.com/saidakyuz/test-vue-props-wih-cypress

As a solution SubComp3 returns individual element of reference types, but I would like to have possibility to return full array or object in case I need to use it.

Can someone help me to find out a solution?

Comment: Take a look how to create a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Not sure but do you mean [Custom Events](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a good way copying reference objects without it's reference connection. So that main component won't be affected from changes on child component.

Changes I made(shallow);

from:
`var cObjectString=this.pObjectString`

to:
`var cObjectString={...this.pObjectString}`

But shallow doesn't work for array object. For that I have used deepclone as following;

from:
`var cObjectArray =this.pObjectArray`

to:
`var cObjectArray = cloneDeep(this.pObjectArray)`

In this article you can get more information about [shallow or deep clone reference types](https://blog.logrocket.com/methods-for-deep-cloning-objects-in-javascript/)

Comment: I have just edited the answer @BDL

Comment: Looks better now. The downvote is not from me.